# Agda Unresolved Metas

Tags: proof, agda

I have created a Tree datatype. And a get function that should retrieve a value from it. I now want to create a Proof that retrieving any Value from an Empty Tree will return "nothing".

(I emitted the get' and Tree' definitions as I don't think they are relevant. If they are needed I will include them)

```
    data Tree (A : Set) : Set where 
        Empty : Tree A
        Nodes : Tree' A -> Tree A
```

```
    get : {A : Set} -> Positive -> Tree A -> Maybe A
    get _ Empty = nothing
    get p (Nodes n) = get' p n
```

```
    data Positive : Set where 
        xH : Positive
        xI : Positive -> Positive
        xO : Positive -> Positive
```

```
gempty : (p : Positive) -> get p Tree.Empty ≡ nothing
gempty p = refl
```

Running this code using "agda ./proofs.agda" I always run into

```
Unsolved metas at the following locations:
  .../src/proofs.agda:12,28-31
```

pointing to the `get` of gempty.

As I have used the get function in other parts of my project and there I could use it im assuming that the problem is directly in the proof declaration.

However, I am new to Agda and don't know how to resolve this issue. If you could point me in the right direction to fix my problem that would be much appreciated.

Edit: Minimal Example

```
open import Data.Maybe
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; cong; cong-app)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning

data Tree' (A : Set) : Set where 
        node001 : Tree' A -> Tree' A

data Tree (A : Set) : Set where 
        Empty : Tree A
        Nodes : Tree' A -> Tree A 

data Positive : Set where 
    xH : Positive
    xI : Positive -> Positive
    xO : Positive -> Positive

get' : {A : Set} -> Positive -> Tree' A -> Maybe A 
get' xH (node001 _ ) = nothing
get' (xO q) (node001 _ )= nothing
get' (xI q) (node001 r )= get' q r

get : {A : Set} -> Positive -> Tree A -> Maybe A
get _ Empty = nothing
get p (Nodes n) = get' p n


gempty : {A : Set} -> ∀ (p : Positive) -> get p Tree.Empty ≡ nothing
gempty p = refl
```

Comment: Can you post minimal self-contained code?

Comment: @user2667523 Hi, Thanks for the response. I added a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agda tells you the unsolved meta is:

```
_A_27 : Set
```

i.e. it doesn't know what type `A` is in the application of `get`. This makes sense as `Tree.Empty` can be a tree of any type. Therefore you have to pass the type `A` that you've declared at the start of the type, explicitly, either for the `{A}` parameter in `get` or the `{A}` parameter in `Tree.Empty`.

Therefore either of the following works:

```
gempty : {A : Set} -> ∀ (p : Positive) -> get {A = A} p Tree.Empty ≡ nothing
```

or

```
gempty : {A : Set} -> ∀ (p : Positive) -> get p (Tree.Empty {A = A}) ≡ nothing
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! I have not found this notation anywhere else while searching for this.

Comment: No worries. See https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.4/language/implicit-arguments.html for further details.